# php foreach loop and addmore button in a form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, foreach

hello i am using a form to add experience to users where i have a add more button which adds more (clones) the content and users get one more field to add experience

i am using this code to achieve this

```
<div id="append_palllsjjs"><div class="full_exp_9092k" id='duplicater'>
                    <div class="full_one_row_009so">
                <div class="obe_left_dibbhsy78">
                            <div class="header_009sos00dd_d">
                        Company Name <span>*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="maind_TAxefst67s77s">
                        <input type="text" name="comp[]" required placeholder="company Name" class='cname_990s_EXp'/>
                    </div>
                        </div><div class="obe_left_dibbhsy78">
                            <div class="header_009sos00dd_d">
                        Department Name <span>*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="maind_TAxefst67s77s">
                        <input type="text" name="dept[]" required placeholder="Department Name" class='cname_990s_EXp'/>
                    </div>
                        </div>
               </div><div class="full_one_row_009so">
                <div class="obe_left_dibbhsy78">
                            <div class="header_009sos00dd_d">
                        From Date <span>*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="maind_TAxefst67s77s">
                         <input type="date" data-initial-day="1" data-initial-year="2011" data-initial-month="9" class='TEx_About_allihh' name="exsdate[]" required/>
                    </div>
                        </div><div class="obe_left_dibbhsy78">
                            <div class="header_009sos00dd_d">
                        To Date <span>*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="maind_TAxefst67s77s">
                          <input type="date" data-initial-day="1" data-initial-year="2012" data-initial-month="10" class='TEx_About_allihh' name="exedate[]" required/>
                    </div>
                        </div>
               </div><div class="full_one_row_009so">
                <div class="obe_left_dibbhsy78">
                            <div class="header_009sos00dd_d">
                        Profile <span>*</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="maind_TAxefst67s77s">
                        <input type="text" name="profile[]" required placeholder="Profile" class='cname_990s_EXp'/>
                    </div>
                        </div><div class="obe_left_dibbhsy78">
               <div class="header_009sos00dd_d">
                                       </div>
                            <input type="button" name="addmore" value="Add More" class='button small white' onclick='duplicate();'/>
                        </div>
               </div>
                </div></div>
```

js

```
  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

 function duplicate() {
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; // there can only be one element with  an ID
 original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
 }
```

here i want the new fields when added should be empty (right now it is showing the same content with pre filled values in textbox )

second issue is i want to insert the data in table for each value of the array i know this can be donr by foreach loop

PHP

```
 $comps=$_POST['comp'];
    $profile=$_POST['profile'];
    $exedate=$_POST['exedate'];
    $exsdate=$_POST['exsdate'];
    $dept=$_POST['dept'];
    if(empty($comps) || empty($profile) || empty($exedate) || empty($exsdate) || empty($dept) ){
        echo 'Please Fill all the fields marked with *';die;
    }
    foreach($comps as $value){
        // insert into tablename (field1,field2,field3,...) values ('comp1','dep1','profile1'....)
```

// insert as many feilds as the no of elements in the array
        }

please suggest me with this php code how to use the foreach loop so that i can insert as many rows as the no of elements in the array with corrosponging values in another array

pleaes note that this question has two questions written please feel free to help for any of the question.

one is wth php and anothr with ajax

Comment: Please explain in brief

Comment: you want to fix this problem using pure javascript OR using jQuery ?

Comment: @SunnyS.M any thing can be helpfull

Comment: @NanaPartykar sir, i want to insert vales to database for each value of an array and also match the corrosponding values in another array

Comment: your first problem fixed.. Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to clear Cloned form :

> NOTE : Must add jquery file in document

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var i = 0;
 var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

  function duplicate(){ 
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    i = ++i;
    clone.id = "duplicetor"+ i; // there can only be one element with  an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    clearCloneForm(clone.id);
  }

  function clearCloneForm(id){ 
    var divId = '#'+id;
    $(divId).find("input[type^='text'], input[type^='date']").each(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    }); 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: hello sir, can you help me how to add a remove button here

Comment: yes happy to help... Please tell what can do for you ?

Comment: i want to add a remove button to the cloned div. so that if user changes his/her mind they can remove the cloned div.

Comment: No problem sister.. Happy to help

Comment: Dear sir, Please let me know if you figure out how to do this ??

Comment: Now in office having lots of work... I figured out how it will solve,

Comment: Hi Sonam changes applied please check new answer code, Here is one problem to remove specific form part need to click two times. I will fix this issue later.

Comment: two times click issue also fixed... Please check code now its pretty work as per your requirement..

Answer (score 1):

Here is code with your new requirement :

> To Add remove button if user want to remove form block section user
>   can easily :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var i = 0;
 var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

  function duplicate(){ 
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    i = ++i;
    clone.id = "duplicetor"+ i; // there can only be one element with  an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    addButton(clone.id,i);
    clearCloneForm(clone.id);
  }

  function clearCloneForm(id){ 
    var divId = '#'+id;
    $(divId).find("input[type^='text'], input[type^='date']").each(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
  }

  function addButton(id,ii){ 
    var divId = '#'+id;
    $(divId).append('<input type="button" value="Remove" class="button small white" id="'+ii+'" onclick="rBlock('+ii+')" />');
  }



function rBlock(ii){
    $('#'+ii).on('click', function(e){ 
        var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
        if(parentDiv.attr('id') !== ii){
            parentDiv.remove();
        }
    });
    $('#'+ii).trigger( "click" );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect Thankyou So much for all your effort.

Comment: YOu are one of the best people i have ever talked

Comment: Happy to help always.... God gives us knowledge we must help other.... we learn always from other...

Comment: Many Thanks for your question